# backbone template and Laravel form open

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, laravel

I just have something come across my mind that how Laravel `Form::open()` should work using Backbone template. I am going to create a html template and let text.js to get the content and shows on the page. Since I use jquery to append this template content which is a form into the page. I am pretty sure if I put `Form::open()` in the template and append it to the page later will not work since laravel only read it and render it. Then I have two questions related to both the topic, and backbone with laravel.

1. Do I need to hardcode the form into the html template? As well as the hidden input for the restful. Can I have some code samples to take a look.
2. if I build a one-page web application, the views of the laravel will be rarely used since I have the html template for Backbone.

Comment: This tutorial is very helpful for answering your question:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/understanding-backbone-js-and-the-server/

Comment: Just dropping this one: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Laravel only runs on the server side in PHP so injected html with jQuery will not work with form open. So will need to load the templates into the page, either precompile them with Grunt or one of the other tools. Or put them in script tags on the page. Then use underscorejs to compile the template with the data and inject it. This is where you could pass the CSRF token into the html form by getting the value from somewhere else where it was on page load and inject into the form.